# Refactoring - Replace all Fieldnames Starting with "_"

Tags: regex, eclipse, intellij-idea, refactoring, structural-search

I'm about to refactor my project and I'd like to replace all variable names that start with "_" e.g. `private final String _name; -> private final String name;`

My Template fo FIND the Variables is simply:

```
$FieldName$
```

I set this regex for the variable name:

```
[_][a-z]+
```

Well, But this will just return a list of my variables starting with "_", how do I strip the _ and then set the new variable name?

**EDIT:** I edited this topic so maybe Eclipse users can tell me how to solve this with **Eclipse**.

Comment: Did you try structural search and replace in IntelliJ?

Comment: Yes but this won't allow you to rename fields.

Answer (score 3):

The following works for me when using IntelliJ IDEA's Structural Search and Replace

Using your Search template, use the following Replacement template:

```
$NewName$
```

With Script text:

```
// FieldName refers to the Search template variable
if (FieldName instanceof com.intellij.psi.PsiVariable) {
  com.intellij.psi.PsiVariable var = (com.intellij.psi.PsiVariable) FieldName;
  var.getName().substring(1);
} else {
  String string = FieldName.getText();
  int index = string.indexOf('_');
  string.substring(0, index) + string.substring(index + 1);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this on a text basis via regular expressions in IntelliJ

Hit *ctrl-shift-r* to open "Replace in Path". Ensure `Regular Expression` is ticked, and enter the following:

Text to find: `([_])([a-zA-Z]+)`

Replace with: `$2`

Beware, a possible issue here is that other text strings (e.g. `EXIT_ON_CLOSE`) might also be picked up by the regular expression, and you might have to be careful not to apply the replace in those cases (or adjust your regular expression to be smarter).